# unicode char or multibyte char:which type is more efficient? why?

Tags: c++, unicode, multibyte

What is the difference between

```
wchar_t arry[]
```

and

```
char arry[]
```

type initialization.
For `Unicode` I know character I know it has several format of encoding. In which `windows` use `UTF-16`. Which means most characters are 16 bit. But in `char` type one character is 8bit. Does that means we can store 2byte in `wchar` type?

Which type is more efficient? Why?

Comment: Almost none of your assumptions are correct (or even near), so it's almost impossible to answer this. (By the way, Soviet Russia uses UTC+4.)

Comment: [UTC-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9208:00) is the Pacific time zone in North America. I think you mean [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are variable-length on Windows (where wchar_t implies UTF-16) and the later is wasteful for most test out there. Even in CJK half the text transferred through the net is ASCII.

[The most portable and easiest way to support Unicode is to use UTF-8 (char)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful). It implies small performance penalty when converting to UTF-16 in order to pass the strings to the Windows API, but it's relatively minor compared to the system calls.

Comment: The statement "`wchar_t` == UTF-16" is misleading. One is a C data type, the other is a text encoding.

Comment: @KerrekSB: better? Also note that "Multibyte encoding" and "Widechar" are terms used by Microsoft as synonyms for "some byte oriented encoding" and "UTF-16". Although I agree that the terminology is incorrect.

Comment: A correct statement would be that Windows stores UTF-16 encoded text in `wchar_t` strings which it calls "wide strings".

Answer (score -1):

Multibyte is a variable width encoding. You will use 1 byte when working in English, but usually 2 or more (up to 6 bytes) for very uncommon character sets. So, in terms of memory usage, multibyte is usually better.
However, when you need to know how many character are in your string, in unicode you can just divide the string length by 2 (sizeof (wchar_t)). in multibyte you have to go over the entire string and count the number of letters.
see [multibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding).

Comment: "Multibyte" isn't an encoding at all. It is a **property** of an encoding: An encoding is either multi-byte or fixed-width.

Comment: Almost every aspect of this answer is incorrect, actually.